# Connect to MariaDB remote server using RStudio

Tags: mysql, r, odbc, mariadb

I am trying this code to connect to the MariaDB in the Red Hat Linux remote server in R.

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
  driver = ????? ,
  database = "test_db",
  UID    = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database user"),
  PWD    = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password"),
  host = "xxx.xx.xx",
  port = ????? )
```

Does this above function help connect to the MariaDB in the remote server?

I am not aware of **what goes under the *driver* argument** in the above function in case of MariaDB.

Also How can I find the *port* number for the remote server I am using?

Please help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: I have never connected to MariaDB/MySQL from R, so I can't give an exact answer, but [read here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/about-mariadb-connector-odbc/) to get most of your questions answered.  The default port would be `3306`, and the driver would just be the name of the driver you are using.  Question upvoted as I can find nothing remotely close to it on SO, and general coverage seems weak here.

Comment: Also you need to create a mysql user in your database server and point that user to your R machine....like `CREATE USER 'youchooseanusername'@'ipofthermachine' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword';`...once that step is done, you need to grant privileges to that user in order to access all, or a specific database.